# Get postlist for each category using query_posts?

Tags: posts, query-posts

```
<?php
 $cat_name=array('Breaking News Stories', 'Call-out', 'Featured Story', 'Standard Stories');
 $count=count($cat_name);
 /*Get category_id by its name*/

 for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++)
  {
  $cat_id5.="'".get_cat_ID($cat_name[$i])."',";
  //$cat_id4.="'".$cat_id5;
  }
 echo  $id1=rtrim($cat_id5,',');
 //query_posts("cat=$catIDs&showposts=4");
 $args=query_posts(array(
                  'category__in' => array($id1),
                  'posts_per_page' => -1,
                // 'category_name' => array('breaking-news-stories',);
                 //'category_name' =>  array('category_name' ,'breaking-news-stories')

         ));
  $posts_array = get_posts($args);
  print_r($posts_array);
 ?>
```

When I'm using the above code, I'm getting the first 5 posts. I want to get all the post by the above mentioned **ID**.
Guide me how to get that!
I'm new to wordpress.

Comment: Are you trying to get a list of posts under each of the categories. Just to note, in my previous answer I've adviced not to use `query_posts` and also `category_name` takes a string, not array.

Comment: if i use WP_Query(),it shows Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function WP_Query() in

Comment: Yes I'm trying to get all post under each category

Comment: Even I'm getting the same result while using the WP_Query()

Comment: Ok, then you are using it wrongly, :-). I will post a proper solution, just let me know first, do you need to make a list of these categories with all the posts under it

Comment: :-( yes I'm trying to get all the post under each category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of queries is completely wrong, and as stated before, `query_posts` should never be used. The method you are using to retrieve you category ID's are also a waste of resources. It would save much more if you knew the ID's.

I would also look at [`get_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) to retrieve my category details and passing that to my custom query.

**METHOD 1**

If these categories are all the categories in your blog, you don't need to know the category name or ID of the specific category to continue. You can retrieve that all with `get_categories` (check out all the available arguments and how they are used). In your `foreach` loop, you can then just pass the `cat_ID` to the `cat` parameter in your `WP_Query`

```
$categories = get_categories();
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=1&cat=' . $category->cat_ID );

    if($query->have_posts()){
        while($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
           //WHATEVER YOU NEED TO DISPLAY
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

**METHOD 2**

If you just need to get these few categories, and don't have the ID's, you can add the names in an array and use [`get_cat_ID`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_ID) to get the ID's and then pass it in the same way as **METHOD 1**

```
$cat_names=array('Breaking News Stories', 'Call-out', 'Featured Story', 'Standard Stories');

foreach ( $cat_names as $cat_name ) {
    $cat_id = get_cat_ID( $cat_name );

    $query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=-1&cat=' . $cat_id );

     // REST IS SAME AS IN METHOD 1

} // end of foreach loop
```